# Razor Components (Blazor) - render-mode affecting lists of derived classes

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I've got a Razor Component i'm dropping onto a Razor page like so:

```
<component type="typeof(ElementProductComponent)"
render-mode="Server"
param-elementList="Model.elementList" />
```

I'm passing a list (elementList) into the component as a parameter.

The list is declared in the razor page code behind as

```
 [BindProperty]    
public List<ElementModel> elementList { get; set; }
```

ElementModel is a base class. The list will normally contain items of various types derived from the base class (ElementTextModel, ElementDateModel, etc)

In the codebind for the razor page the list is populated like this:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(string id)
    {
        elementList = GetList();

        return Page();
    }
    public static List<ElementModel> GetList()
    {
        var elements = new List<ElementModel>();

        elements.Add(new ElementTextModel { Name = "TestTextName", Value = "hello world" });
        elements.Add(new ElementDateModel { Name = "TestDateName", Value = "20200101" });

        return elements;

    }
```

The models look like this:

```
public class ElementModel
{

    [Required] 
    public string Name { get; set; }


    [Required] 
    public virtual ElementType Type { get; }



}

 public class ElementTextModel : ElementModel
{

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Hashtable Attributes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public override ElementType Type { get { return ElementType.TEXT; } }
}
```

Then in my component, I want to iterate over the list and display different html, child components based on the type of each item in the list. I can do that that with a switch or if. Here is a simplified version of the code where I'm just trying to display the type I see.

```
    <div>
    Elements:
    <ul>
        @for (var i = 0; i < elementList.Count; i++)
        {
        <li>       
                <div>@elementList[i].Type</div>
                <div>@elementList[i].Name</div>

        </li>

        }
    </ul>
</div>
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public List<ElementModel> elementList { get; set; }

}
```

The issue is that when I declare the component like

```
<component type="typeof(ElementProductComponent)"
render-mode="Server"
param-elementList="Model.elementList" />
```

with the render-mode set to Server, the code in the component sees the items in the elementList as of type ElementModel, regardless of how they were declared. This isn't correct.

if I do this:

```
<component type="typeof(ElementProductComponent)"
render-mode="Static"
param-elementList="Model.elementList" />
```

and set the render-mode to Static, the component sees the list correctly, as a mixed list of items of types derived from the base class.

Why is this happening? Is this a bug or is there some configuration issue at play?

Comment: I can reproduce same issue. And I checked [the source code of RazorComponents/ComponentRenderer.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/602cb1dea59751a1297d674cddf7f0729c23e6ca/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/RazorComponents/ComponentRenderer.cs#L53), it seems that if RenderMode is Server, it would perform additional serialization, which might cause the issue. If possible, you can try to [open an issue on github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues) to reprot it.